# Convert ES6 to use Webpack Code Splitting with System.import?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, code-splitting

Can anyone explain to me how to convert this es6 code example into a code splittable chunk via webpack?  I haven't been able to find any other good examples.

```
import flexslider from 'flexslider';
import jqueryEasing from 'jquery-easing';
import './about.less';

export class About { 
                attached()
                {
                //do something here
                }
}
```